# How do you read the state of the iOS bluetooth app settings switch programmatically?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS app that uses bluetooth. I see a bluetooth switch in the app settings screen iOS populates automatically. How do I read the state of that switch?

[image]

I tried using CentralManager to see if ble power is enabled and so on, but that's not really the same thing.

Comment: The only way to know it in your ios application is to listen to the changes using [`didUpdateState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518888-centralmanagerdidupdatestate) delegate or by polling the `CBManager.state` property. Unless ofcourse you don't think hacking the ios system :)). Think of it; this is not a bare metal programming envorinment, you can't read it as you do in an embedded app where you read a pin state. There is an OS that rules your application and you have to obey its rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to determine the state of Bluetooth permission for your app: `CBCentralManager.authorization`